# strongloop component : strong-oracle -> npm test failures on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: strongloop

I am trying to build/test strong-oracle by cloning the latest top of the tree from github : https://github.com/strongloop/strong-oracle/

i have installed the oracle instant client 12.1 for my machine and set the environment variables in bashrc as below ::

```
export OCI_LIB_DIR=/opt/instantclient_12_1
export OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=$OCI_LIB_DIR/sdk/include
export OCI_HOME=/opt/instantclient_12_1
export OCI_VERSION=12
export OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/instantclient_12_1/sdk/includeenter 
if [ -f ~/strong-oracle.rc ]; then
source ~/strong-oracle.rc
fi

root@pts00433-vm24:~/strong-oracle# node --version
v4.2.2
root@pts00433-vm24:~/strong-oracle# npm --version
2.14.7
root@pts00433-vm24:~/strong-oracle# nodejs --version
v0.10.25
```

Now while building using npm install and npm test ,please see below.

```
root@pts00433-vm24:~/strong-oracle# npm install
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.2.1 should be installed with -g
npm WARN cannot run in wd oracle@0.3.8 node-gyp rebuild (wd=/root/strong-oracle/node_modules/oracle)
npm WARN cannot run in wd strong-oracle@1.8.0 node-gyp rebuild (wd=/root/strong-oracle)
```

Next while performing npm test , i am getting below errors:

```
    root@pts00433-vm24:~/strong-oracle# npm test
    > strong-oracle@1.8.0 pretest /root/strong-oracle
    > node pretest.js
    module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^
    Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/oracle_bindings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/strong-oracle/lib/oracle.js:15:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details
```

Any pointers on resolving this would be helpful.

Comment: It probably isn't the problem, but you should consider uninstalling the nodejs package from Ubuntu. Nothing good will confer from have two incompatible versions of node installed/active at the same time.

Comment: i uninstalled the nodejs package from ubunut , however the errors are still the same.

Comment: root@pts00433-vm24:~/strong-oracle# npm test
Error: /opt/instantclient_12_1/libocci.so.12.1: undefined symbol: __IBMCPlusPlusExceptionV3
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:460:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/strong-oracle/lib/oracle.js:11:14)
 npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
Any pointers how to resolve the above error.

Comment: Are you using the IBM node SDK? Do you get the same errors with the nodejs.org version?

Comment: I am not using ibm node sdk , yes i get the same error with nodejs.org version.

Comment: instant client basic : http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/121020/instantclient-basic-linux.leppc64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
instant client sdk - http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/121020/instantclient-sdk-linux.leppc64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
instant client sql plus - http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/instantclient/121020/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.leppc64-12.1.0.2.0.zip